How to Solve Law of Demeter Violation in Java Records?
I am using the below record in my Quarkus application and at some point I need to access the requestId field, located in Statements nested record. I want to avoid using the getters provided by the nested records since this will invoke a Law of Demeter violation. I tried to add a fifth field named Statements in KYAAutoResponse record and then use a custom method to gain access to requestId automatically but this returns null.
I am a little confused on how could I bypass the violation. Can you help me?
public record KYAAutoResponse(
        DataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord dataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord
) {
    public record DataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord(
            Data data
    ) {
        public record Data(
                Document document
        ) {
            public record Document(
                    Statements statements
            ) {
                @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                public record Statements(
                        @JsonProperty("request-id") String requestId
                ) {}
            }
        }
    }
}


Well, some of us are equally confused ;) I must confess I cannot reason deeply enough about nested records, but wouldn't it help to declare the hierarchy inverted? I.e. start with Statements, then Document, etc. Then you can decompose with record patterns. Or?

If you want to adhere to the LoD then you have three alternatives: (i) figure out how KYAAutoResponse() can do without the requestId; (ii) figure out how to make the requestId available to KYAAutoResponse() from another source, such as directly as one of its parameters, or (iii) augment or restructure the data so that you can get the requestId from it directly.

I made the decision to follow the below approach which I think it's the closest in solving my problem. I placed methods in each of the nested records that call the next one. This means that KYAAutoResponse object knows the internals of DataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord etc.
public record GovResponse(
        DataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord dataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord
) {

    public String getRequestId() {
        return dataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord.getRequestId();
    }

    public record DataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord(
            Data data
    ) {

        public String getRequestId() {
            return data.getRequestId();
        }

        public record Data(
                Document document
        ) {

            public String getRequestId() {
                return document.getRequestId();
            }

            public record Document(
                    Statements statements
            ) {

                public String getRequestId() {
                    return statements.requestId;
                }

                @JsonbNillable
                public record Statements(
                        @JsonbProperty("request-id") String requestId
                ) {}
            }
        }
    }
}


If I understand correctly, you want to be able to do kyaAutoResponse.requestId().
This will allow you to do this:
public record KYAAutoResponse(
    DataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord dataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord,
    long callSequenceId,
    String callSequenceDate
) {
    public record DataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord(
        Data data
    ) {
        public record Data(
            Document document
        ) {
            public record Document(
                Statements statements
            ) {
                @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
                public record Statements(
                    @JsonProperty("request-id") String requestId,
                    @JsonProperty("consent_content") String data
                ) {}
            }
        }
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Optional<String> requestId() {
        if (dataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord == null) return Optional.empty();
        if (dataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord.data == null) return Optional.empty();
        if (dataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord.data.document == null) return Optional.empty();
        if (dataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord.data.document.statements == null) return Optional.empty();
        return Optional.ofNullable(dataTransFlowAccessOutputRecord.data.document.statements.requestId);
    }
}


Thank you for your answer. Does your requestId() method break the Law of Demeter?

Yes, but it's isolated in the record structure and if you need to access requestId what else can you do?  I think this is preferable to having the chain-walking outside of this structure.  Of course, if you also need to accessdata, I'd consider mapping the hierarchical structure to something flatter.
